# JMS Message failed to receive

Tags: jms, stomp, jms-topic

I have a  connection session pool, through which the listener class receive the message being published on the topic using StompJMS selector via apollo (apache-apollo-1.7.1).

Say I've 4 objects (ob1, ob2, ob3, ob4) listening from the topic using the same connection session pool,firstly the registration  request has been sent for all 4 objects using the 4 selectors (s1, s2, s3, s4) to receive a set of features (a, b, c) from topic.
The DeliveryMode is set to Persistent for jms Producer. 
The selectors look like:

s1: "((SYMBOL_NAME='ob1.name()') AND ( MESSAGE_TYPE='SIGNAL') AND ((SIGNAL_NAME='A') OR (SIGNAL_NAME='B') OR (SIGNAL_NAME='C') OR(SIGNAL_NAME='D'))"

s2: "((SYMBOL_NAME='ob2.name()') AND( MESSAGE_TYPE='SIGNAL') AND ((SIGNAL_NAME='A') OR (SIGNAL_NAME='B') OR (SIGNAL_NAME='C') OR(SIGNAL_NAME='D'))"

s3: "((SYMBOL_NAME='ob3.name()') AND( MESSAGE_TYPE='SIGNAL') AND ((SIGNAL_NAME='A') OR (SIGNAL_NAME='B') OR (SIGNAL_NAME='C') OR(SIGNAL_NAME='D'))"

s4: "((SYMBOL_NAME='ob4.name()') AND ( MESSAGE_TYPE='SIGNAL') AND ((SIGNAL_NAME='A') OR (SIGNAL_NAME='B') OR (SIGNAL_NAME='C') OR(SIGNAL_NAME='D'))"

Another java application is publishing the features a, b, c for ob1, ob2, ob3, ob4 on a topic.

The listener class is receiving the values for any 3 say (ob1, ob2, ob3) , but its' not receiving the values for ob4, and sometimes it's receiving for (ob1, ob3, ob4) and not for ob2. The object its' not receiving for is not fixed.

One reason I can think of is the jms selector failed to pick up features for ob4 or other can be the apollo connection broke down, later seems to be very unlikely because in that case other objects would also have been affected.

Please let me know if there's an issue with the selector.

Comment: Doesn't look any problem with s4. To debug the issue you can use the selector used in s3 for obj4 and see if it is getting the message. If this happens then there is some problem with selector else problem with listener itself.

Comment: Thanks @HarKrishan, but the object for which the listener it's not receiving isn't fixed, sometimes it misses for ob1, or sometimes any other.

Comment: In that case the chances are selector is not qualifying the message but you are thinking that you are missing the message. Log the selector criteria and observe the missing scenario carefully.